# Can $Z\mid Y=y$ be a random variable?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X$, $Y$ be random variable. I saw several post where it's says that $X\mid Y=y$ is not a random variable. But what about this example ?

Set $Z=f(X,Y)$ for a Borel function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Isn't it correct that $Z\mid Y=y=f(X,y)$ where $$(Z|Y=y )(\omega )=f(X(\omega ),y) \ \ ?$$
And thus, in this case $(Z\mid Y=y):\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable, no ?

For example, if $f(x,y)=e^{x-y}$, then $$(Z\mid Y=y)=e^{-y}e^X,$$
which is a random variable, no ?

Comment: $Y=y$ is an event corresponding to a subset of $\Omega$, so $(Z\mid Y=y):\Omega \to \mathbb R$ does not look meaningful

Comment: I agree with @Henry ‘s comment, the mapping has little to no meaning since $\{Y=y\}=\{\omega\in \Omega:Y(\omega)=y\}$ is a subset of $\Omega$. “Conditional random variable” is essentially abuse of language for “random variable with conditional distribution”.